# Random variable X has Uniform Distribution on section $[-2,4]$. What's the probability of $P(0\leq X \leq7)$

Tags: probability

Random variable X has Uniform Distribution on section $[-2,4]$. What's the probability of $P(0\leq X\leq7)$

$b-a=6$

It can't be $\frac{7}{6}$ because probability has to be $p\geq0$ and  $p\leq1$

What am I doing wrong here?

Should it be only $P(X=5)+P(X=6)+P(X=7)$ since uniforms distribution ends on $4$?

Comment: This is presumably a *continuous distribution*, not just a discrete one.  No, $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$, including those $x\in[-2,4]$ which are just so unlikely that they get a probability of zero as well as those $x$ outside of $[-2,4]$ which are flatout impossible.

Comment: This should be solved with calculus (*or simply geometry*).  Note that $P(0\leq X\leq 7) = P(0\leq X\leq 4) + P(4<X\leq 7)$.  Note that this second part here is very obviously zero since none of those values are even possible so this simplifies to $P(0\leq X\leq 7) = P(0\leq X\leq 4)$.  Can you finish now?

Comment: @JMoravitz $p=\frac{4}{6}?$ since $P(0)=P(1)=P(2)=P(3)$ so $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: There you go treating this like a discrete distribution again.  You got the right answer but for the wrong reason.  $P(0)=P(1)=P(2)=P(3)=0$.  What we are interested in is the **area** *under the* **curve**.$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x<-2\\\frac{1}{6}&\text{if }-2\leq x\leq 4\\0&\text{if }x>4\end{cases}$ over the region $[0,7]$... that is, we are looking for $\int\limits_0^7 f(x)dx$.  Avoiding calculus terminology... we want the *length of the interval* (*which overlaps our sample space*) divided by the length of the sample space.

Comment: The integers who happen to be in the interval have nothing to do with this.  We could also have asked about $Pr(0.2<X<0.8)$ which would be $\frac{0.6}{6}=0.1$.  This has nothing to do with $P(X=0), P(X=1),$ etc...

Answer (score 1):

The density is a rectangle with base 6 and height $\frac{1}{6}$ so the total probability is $6\times \frac{1}{6}=1$

Saying $P[0<X<7]=P[0<X<4]$ because any value greater than 4 has probability density = zero.

Thus the requested probability is the area of a rectangle with base 4 and height $\frac{1}{6}$

Result: $4\times \frac{1}{6}=\frac{4}{6}$